# segmentation fault while heapifying

Tags: c

I was simply heapifying an array in C. But while running it's giving me segmentation fault(core dumped)... i have no idea where i am trying to access unallocated memory!!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int n;

int left(i)
{
    return (2*i);
}

int right(i)
{
    return (2*i + 1);
}


void min_heap(int a[],int i)
{
    int l=left(i);
    int r=right(i);
    int min;

    if((l<=n)&&(a[l]<=a[i])&&(a[l]<=a[r]))
    {
        min=a[l];
        a[i]=a[i]+a[l];
        a[l]=a[i]-a[l];
        a[i]=a[i]-a[l];
    }
    else if((r<=n)&&(a[r]<=a[i])&&(a[r]<=a[l]))
    {
        min=a[r];
        a[i]=a[i]+a[r];
        a[r]=a[i]-a[r];
        a[i]=a[i]-a[r];
    }

    min_heap(a,min);
}



int main()
{
    printf("The no is : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i,a[n+1];

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=n/2;i>=1;i--)
    {
        min_heap(a,i);
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: N o t  a  r e a d a b l e  c o d e!

Comment: I'm not clear what the computations in the `if` and `else` block are supposed to be doing; it doesn't look like a straight-forward swap.  You check that `l <= n` but if `l == n` then `r > n` and you will have problems as you access `a[r]`. If your array is of size 10 (`n == 10`) and the values in your array are 1000000 and upwards, your use of `min = a[l];` or `min = a[r];` means you'll recurse on an array that's supposed to be vastly bigger than it actually is.  And having a global variable `n` is tacky; pass it as a parameter to the functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: those are swaps (but not straightforward). I'd suggest changing them to be plain old swaps using a temporary. Especially since `min` is already there as a temporary.

Comment: I agree that they are swaps, but I'd shoot anyone who sent me code to review that swapped using that many irrelevant operations. It's not only obscure, it's wasteful.  Granted, waste is relative, but ...

Answer (score 0):

You call `min_heap(a,i)` when `i == n/2`.

In this case, inside `min_heap()` the call to `right()` will return in effect:

```
(2 * (n/2) + 1)
```

When `n` is even that will result in a right index of `n+1` and accessing `a[r]` (with `r == n+1`) is beyond the end of the array you've allocated.

I'm not sure if this is the reason for your segfault; I'd guess there may be other problems.

You should probably just step through a run with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from [More Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201118890) by Jon Bentley, written as comments in a C file.  The full code is not relevant to you; it is generic interface like the interface to `bsearch()` and `qsort()`, but this is written in `awk`.

```
/*
** See Appendix 2 of Jon Bentley "More Programming Pearls".
** See also Column 14 of Jon Bentley "Programming Pearls, 2nd Edn".
** Note that MPP algorithms are in terms of an array indexed from 1.
** C, of course, indexes arrays from zero.
**
** 1-based identities.
** root          = 1
** value(i)      = x(i)
** leftchild(i)  = 2*i
** rightchild(i) = 2*i+1
** parent(i)     = i/2
** null(i)       = (i < 1) or (i > n)
**
** 0-based identities.
** root          = 0
** value(i)      = x(i)
** leftchild(i)  = 2*(i+1)-1   = 2*i+1
** rightchild(i) = 2*(i+1)+1-1 = leftchild(i)+1
** parent(i)     = (i+1)/2-1
** null(i)       = (i < 0) or (i >= n)  # NB: i < 0 irrelevant for unsigned numbers
*/

/*
**  function swap(i, j  t) {
**      # x[i] :=: x[j]
**      t = x[i]
**      x[i] = x[j]
**      x[j] = t
**  }
**
**  function siftup(l, u,    i, p) {
**      # pre  maxheap(l, u-1)
**      # post maxheap(l, u)
**      i = u
**      while (1) {
**          # maxheap(l, u) except between i and its parent
**          if (i <= l) break
**          p = int(i/2)        # p = parent(i)
**          if (x[p] >= x[i]) break
**          swap(p, i)
**          i = p
**      }
**  }
**
**  function siftdown(l, u,  i, c) {
**      # pre  maxheap(l+1, u)
**      # post maxheap(l,u)
**      i = l
**      while (1) {
**          # maxheap(l, u) except between i and its children
**          c = 2*i         # c = leftchild(i)
**          if (c > u) break;
**          if (c + 1 <= u && x[c+1] > x[c]) c++
**          if (x[i] >= x[c]) break
**          swap(c, i)
**          i = c
**      }
**  }
**
**  function hsort(    i) {
**      # post sorted(1, n)
**      for (i = int(n/2); i >= 1; i--)
**          siftdown(i, n)
**      for (i = n; i >= 2; i--) {
**          swap(1, i)
**          siftdown(1, i-1)
**      }
**  }
*/
```

In the code, the array being sorted is `x`, indexed from `1` to `N`.